# How to create a ServiceNow Change Request as a step in TFS 2018 Release

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to create a `ServiceNow` Change Request as one of the steps in my Release. I was trying to `Agentless` Phase step (Invoke Rest API: Post).

I found one article online that suggested to create a Generic Endpoint for `ServiceNow`. I tried that in the step failed, I'm sure I don't have it set up correctly.

2019-11-12T12:55:28.8833838Z POST https://xyzhelpdesk.service-now.com/api/now/table/change_request
                Response Code: 0
                Response: An error was encountered while processing request.

> Exception: {"error":{"message":"Exception while reading request","detail":"Cannot decode: java.io.StringReader@90f857"},"status":"failure"}
>   Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (type WebException)

The endpoint has a username and password defined, but I think in the setup for Step I may need more information in the Header section.

[image]

I can create the CR via a `Powershell` script, I guess I could just use that but Not sure the correct way to go.

Basically I want to create a `ServiceNow` CR as part of my deployment process. Then there is a `TFS` plugin gated step that will check the status on the CR and when it's approves the process moves forward.

Who has examples ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a built-in extension-- [ServiceNow Change Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-servicenowchangerequestmanagement) which provide by Microsoft almost fit your needs.

It includes:

- **A release gate to hold the pipeline till the change management
  process signals implementation for a change request.** You can create a
  new change request for every deployment or use an existing change
  request.
- An agentless task to update a change request during the deployment
  process. It is typically used as the last task in the stage.

However, *this extension works only with Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1 onwards..* Not available to use on tfs2018. You could consider to upgrade your TFS to latest Azure DevOps Version.

With TFS 2018, suggest you to use a powershell script to handle this. It's able to use 
ServiceNow and Azure DevOps Rest API. You could also take a look at great article blogs(similar for TFS):

[Integrating VSTS Release Management with ServiceNow using Deployment Gate for Change Management](https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/IntegratingServiceNowWithVstsReleaseManagementUsingDeploymentGate)

[Implement an Azure DevOps Release Gate to ServiceNow](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/implement-an-azure-devops-release-gate-to-servicenow)

Comment: We are on TFS 2018,, when I try to install it It throws the following error:  

ServiceNow Change Management
 
by Microsoft
 


 



Something's gone wrong

Following errors were found in endpoint contribution:Authentication schemes ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-oauth2, are not valid.

Comment: Hi  Pat Delaney,  sorry for the later reply. We also did some test in our lab environment to try to install  ServiceNow Change Management  on TFS 2018, got similar error. As the official link already pointed out, it's an expect behavior, this extension works only with Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1 onwards.. Not available to use on tfs2018. You may do the customization by yourself to achieve this remands. Otherwise, you have to upgrade your server to Azure DevOps Server 2019.